# Comparing two datasets, to ensure an administrator can only edit users in their area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have created an app where `users` have many `areas` (through `subscriptions`).  Some `users` have the `:admin` role, and these users also have many `administrative_areas` (through `administrations`.  I'm struggling getting my head round the best way to ensure that given an admin of Area A goes to the users index page, they only see other users in Area A, but not those outside of this area.  My model is set up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :areas, through: :subscriptions

  has_many :administrations
  has_many :administrative_areas, through: :administrations, :source => :area, :class_name => "Area"
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

  has_many :administrations
  has_many :admins, :through => :administrations, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
end
```

I can successfully set up the users / admins, but am struggling with getting the right ActiveRecord Query to return only relevant users for the admin.

Any thoughts on solving this, or suggestions for a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `@admin_user` as some user with admin role.

```
  @admin_areas = User.joins(:subscriptions).where('subscriptions.area_id' => @admin_user.administrative_areas.map(&:id))
```

You can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem to `manage` roles and giving controls to different roles.

**EDIT :** You can try something like below

In user.rb

```
scope :users_to_manage, lambda{ joins(:subscriptions).where('subscriptions.area_id' => current_user.administrative_areas.map(&:id)) #if you have access current_user in model
```

In ability.rb

```
can :manage, Area.users_to_manage
```

Comment: I am already using the cancan gem, can you give me any more pointers on how I might configure it to achieve what I'm after above?  At the moment, if the user.has_role? :admin they can simply :manage :all, which feels rather crude!

Comment: Right... that works if I change it to `@admin_areas = Area.where(:id => @admin_user.administrative_areas.map(&:id))` but is there an easy way now to return all the users from those areas in one line AR query?  Thank you!

Comment: Ok I will edit it. It is better to define `scope` in model and then use that scope where u defining role.

Comment: More than happy to take that approach, too.

Comment: Thank you, that seems a smart direction to take, but there's an error on that scope (syntax error, unexpected tIVAR -- don't I need to have defined @admin_areas?!)  Also, it's still not addressing my challenge of only showing the administrator the users of the areas they can administrate.  I'd like users/index to return all users of the areas the current_user is admin of.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Try this to get users of administrative_areas: `User.joins(:subscriptions).where(:area_id => current_user.administrative_areas.map(&:id))`

Comment: That query produces: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "subscriptions"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."area_id" IN (3)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column users.area_id does not exist`

Comment: sorry, `User.joins(:subscriptions).where("subscriptions.area_id" => current_user.administrative_areas.map(&:id))`